# Cart become Empty after 3 to 5 minutes Magento

Tags: magento

I'm working on a store and my cart become empty sometimes after 2,5 minutes or sometimes more upto 35 minutes before placing an order.

I did increase the quote lifetime and the session time too but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can occure in many different situations.

- the item you put on your cart becomes out of stock
- the system is set to keep the session cookie for a short period (but the duration would not be random)
- a module interact badly with the cart
- a caching system is on and the cart is cached as well. therefore, when the cache is invalidated or refreshed, the cart is empty

Comment: I tried  all these situations but its still not working.

Comment: Can you list modules and describe your cache system please ?